# Screenshot with qgraphicsview

Tags: qt, opengl-es

I have a browser application written in qt5 for my embedded board. I need opengl rendering to the aplication .So the code is like

```
myGraphicsView->setViewport(new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::NoDepthBuffer |QGL::NoStencilBuffer |QGL::NoSampleBuffers)));
```

I would like to take the screenshot of the webpage rendered.How can I get it.Worked with QPixmap::grabFrameBuffer and grabWindow.But got only a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

I found in internet and tried, it's worked:

```
//Get the size of your graphicsview
QRect rect = MyGrView->viewport()->rect();

//Create a pixmap the same size as your graphicsview
//You can make this larger or smaller if you want.
QPixmap pixmap(rect.size());
QPainter painter(&pixmap);//QPainter does not support coordinates larger than +/- 32768

//Render the graphicsview onto the pixmap and save it out.
MyGrView->render(&painter, pixmap.rect(), rect);
pixmap.save("C:/1.png","PNG");
```

[QPainter limitations](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#limitations)